# How to detect up and down clicks on html input[number]?

Tags: html, angularjs, html-input

I have an html `<input type="number">` box that has some custom validation logic. A valid value is any integer `x` where `x < -100` OR `x >= 100`.

My goal is to implement this behavior:

1. when the user clicks on the native down arrow or presses the down arrow key and the current value is `100`, the value changes to `-101`.
2. similarly when the user clicks on the native up arrow or presses the up arrow key and the current value is `-101`, the value changes to `100`.

A few caveats:

- Users must still be able to type numbers that fall within the invalid range since they may need to type `10` in order to type `109`. And validation logic already occurs for this.
- I am using angularjs, but I suspect that the solution is not going to be angular specific.
- This is an internal application, meant for Chrome only, so browser specific answers are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have what you need, or at least I'm getting close:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function changeNum(input, typing) {
    var lower=-101, upper=100, x=parseInt(input.value), active=(input==document.activeElement);
    if ((typing && String(Math.abs(x)).length>2 && lower<x&&x<upper) || (!typing && lower<x&&x<upper)) {
      if (Math.abs(x-upper) < Math.abs(x-lower)) {input.value = (!active||typing?upper:lower);}
      else {input.value = (!active||typing?lower:upper);}
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("num").addEventListener("keyup",function(){changeNum(this,true);},false);
  document.getElementById("num").addEventListener("change",function(){changeNum(this,false);},false);
};
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num" value="100" />
```

**jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/9zz0ra35/4/
**codepen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ndqbog

- When the user clicks on the input's up&down-buttons, the value flips over on the lower and upper threshold (`-100 -> 100`, `99 -> -101`).
- When the user types a value and then clicks outside the input, invalid values are changed to the closest threshold (`-100 -> -101`, `99 -> 100`).
- While typing, invalid values are also changed to the closest threshold, but only if the value.length is more than 2 chars (`-100 -> -101`).

  - *This last one isn't as clean as the others, because it only works if both the lower and upper threshold have the same length (in this case 3 chars).

    But if you need thresholds with different lengths, you can always change the `String(Math.abs(x)).length>2` to an extra if-clause and first check whether the value is positive or negative, and then check for separate lengths.*

Comment: Yes. This works. The code itself can do with a bit of cleaning up, but the solution is correct. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg could you perhaps update my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9zz0ra35/4/) with your cleaned up version and comment the link? I always like to learn how to improve my coding

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm getting what you want. Is it something like this?

```js
 var number = document.getElementById('number-input');
 number.onchange = function(event) {
  if(number.value > 100) {
   number.value = -101;
  } else if(number.value < -100) {
   number.value = 101;
  }
 };
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number-input">
```

Comment: It's the right direction, but this won't work.You have the < and > switched. From `-100` to `99` is _invalid_. `100` and more or `-101` and less are _valid_. So, we need to know which whether or not the text box was incrementing or decrementing. And for that we will need to know what the previous value was.